# Display JSON feed on FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a webpage where I would like to display events on FullCalendar. I have a JSON feed which is located on another server (RESTful API), and am fetching it like this:

```
function getData(selector,callback) {
return $.ajax({
    url:"myurl/logs?" + selector,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: callback
})
}
```

The selector is for filtering results. I also have to use the .done selector each time I have to use it (because the asynchronous behavior of ajax).

```
getData().done(function(result){
// my function here
}
```

The results have a JSON format like this:

```
[{"startTime":"2014-10-08T11:57:10.968Z","endTime":"2014-10-08T11:57:15.169Z"}]
```

The FullCalendar only accepts "start" and "end" as identifiers. What do I have to have FullCalendar accept my JSON feed?

Comment: How are you using `getData()`? show fullcalendar configuration

Comment: like this

    `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: result
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [events (as a function)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        getData().done(function(results){
            var events = $.map(results, function(result) {
                return {
                    title: '',
                    start: result.startTime,
                    end: result.endTime 
                };
            });
            callback(events);
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I now get all the logs (1046 in total) in one day, displaying the title `3:21p`. Any idea?

Comment: @username_HI, You need to set `timeFormat` read docs. Also Just curious: Have you created events for 5 seconds? and use `start` and `end` parameters

Comment: I checked in the console, it returns an array of the correct size, but the objects all have the id's `start = undefined`and `end = undefined`. Yes, I am working on a Quantified Self Device and complementary website

Comment: @username_HI, What about `startTime` and `endTime` in you returned JSON?